# MDX Statement explaination required

Tags: ssas, mdx

Please explain the below MDX statement -

```
Axis(1).Item(0).Item (0).Dimension.Levels(0).item(0)
```

If possible please share the output as well (using SSMS analysis services)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Axis(1).Item(0).Item(0).Dimension.Levels(0).Item(0)

The way to figure out what this expression means, is to go through each function from left-to-right, and determine what each one is doing and returning. Let's go through this one function at a time.

1. Axis(1) - Retrieve the set of tuples on the rows axis (the axis at index 1).
2. Item(0) - Retrieve the first tuple from the previously returned set.
3. Item(0) - Retrieve the first member from the previously returned tuple.
4. Dimension - Get the hierarchy from the previously returned member.
5. Levels(0) - Retrieve the first level from the previously returned hierarchy.
6. Item(0) - Retrieve the first member from the previously returned hierarchy level.

Here are the Microsoft function definitions that I used to create the above list.

[Axis()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/axis-mdx)

> Returns the set of tuples on a specified axis.

[Item(Tuple)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/item-tuple-mdx)

> Returns a tuple from a set.

[Item(Member)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/item-member-mdx)

> Returns a member from a specified tuple.

[Dimension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/dimension-mdx)

> Returns the hierarchy that contains a specified member, level, or hierarchy.

[Levels()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/levels-mdx)

> Returns the level whose position in a dimension or hierarchy is specified by a numeric expression or whose name is specified by a string expression.

---

### Edit - Added Example

Check out the Geography dimension and hierarchy from the Adventure Works cube.

[image: Geography Dimension]

There are 5 levels for the Geography hierarchy.

- [Geography].[Geography].[(All)]
- [Geography].[Geography].[Country]
- [Geography].[Geography].[State-Province]
- [Geography].[Geography].[City]
- [Geography].[Geography].[Postal Code]

Let's use your expression on the columns axis (via a calculated member) and select the city, Alexandria, on the rows axis.

```
WITH
    MEMBER [Measures].[SomeMember] AS AXIS(1).ITEM(0).ITEM(0).DIMENSION.LEVELS(0).ITEM(0).MEMBER_CAPTION
SELECT 
    {([Measures].[SomeMember])} ON COLUMNS,
    {([Geography].[Geography].[City].&[Alexandria]&[NSW])} ON ROWS
FROM 
    [Adventure Works]
```

Here is the break-down of what's happening:

1. Axis(1) - Returns the set from the rows axis:
   `{([Geography].[Geography].[City].&[Alexandria]&[NSW])}`
2. ITEM(0) - Returns the set's first tuple:
   `([Geography].[Geography].[City].&[Alexandria]&[NSW])`
3. ITEM(0) - Returns the tuple's first member:
   `[Geography].[Geography].[City].&[Alexandria]&[NSW]`
4. DIMENSION - Returns the member's dimension hierarchy:
   `[Geography].[Geography]`
5. LEVELS(0) - Returns the hierarchy's first level:
   `[Geography].[Geography].[(All)]`
6. ITEM(0) - returns the level's first member:
   `[Geography].[Geography].[(All)].[All Geographies]`

Here are the query results:

[image: Query Results]

Here is a screenshot to help visualize where the All Geographies member is, with respect to the Alexandria member:

[image: All Member]

Comment: Thanks for replying, can you please elaborate with the help of example like considering any cube with dimensions and measures?

Comment: @piyushjain Added an example from the [Adventure Works] cube. Let me know if you need any other clarification.

Comment: Appreciate your response. Thankyou :-)

Comment: I need to convert above MDX into DAX. Can you please suggest while conversion of aboce query into DAX?

Comment: @piyushjain I would recommend creating a new question for that one, since MDX-to-DAX conversion is a bit off topic for this question. By creating a new question, it may draw other users with some DAX knowledge who can help answer.